# XML how to have two numbers under same variable

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine

I have XML sheet that I use in my game.
In my unity(C#) game, a game's monster can spawn at predetermined position or random position.

```
<monster delay="0.2" isRed = "true" position ="random"/>
<monster delay="0.3" isRed = "true" position ="10 20"/>
```

Right now I read value of position and if it is "random" then I assign random position for the monster.

If it is not "random" then I parse the value, separate them by a space bar then use the two numbers I obtain from the "position" as position of my monster.

I get this gut feeling what I am doing is probably really ugly and inefficient that there is probably better way to do this, but I am not sure.

Comment: You could add more elements to the entry.  Such as an IsRandom field, and x-pos and y-pos.  When IsRandom is true ignore the positions.  This will make the values more explicit and remove the parsing of a string into multiple values.

Answer (score 2):

This seems fine. There are probably a lot of different ways to do this, but there's nothing inherently wrong with how you're doing it. If you didn't already have the `random` command in place, I would probably tell you to separate the position coordinates into `posX ="10"` and `posY ="20"`, but since you're already looking for a non-numeric command value, there's nothing wrong with leaving them combined and parsing them. (You *could* separate them and have `random` for both X and Y coordinates, giving you the flexibility to define one and make the other random...)

Comment: Agreed: Requiring micro-parsing of attributes is usually a design flaw.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than require micro-parsing of `@position` to separate `x` and `y`, I'd [agree with Bill the Lizard about using distinct attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49802346/290085).  I'd go further and recommend that you *not* overload `@position` with numeric and non-numeric values but factor out the random case to its own attribute too:

```
<monster delay="0.3" isRed="true" startX="10" startY="20" startRandom="false"/>
```

You might also make the default for `@startRandom` be false, so it would be omitted when coordinates are provided:

```
<monster delay="0.3" isRed="true" startX="10" startY="20"/>
```

Alternatively, you might define the absence of starting coordinates to imply randomness.  Then you'd have the coordinated case,

```
<monster delay="0.3" isRed="true" startX="10" startY="20"/>
```

and the random case,

```
<monster delay="0.3" isRed="true"/>
```

Finally, plan ahead for other color monsters:

```
<monster delay="0.3" color="red" startX="10" startY="20"/>
```

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was some kind of health status indicator, so I didn't mention it, but I like the change from `isRed="true"` to `color="red"`. No position signifying `random` is also a good idea.